What Percent of the Time will a Given Random Walk will Behave a Certain Way?
Suppose I have a 1 Dimensional Random Walk (on the integer line) with the following properties (initial conditions):

At time=0 it starts at position=0
At each time point, there is a 0.5 probability of moving +1 or -1

This Random Walk keeps going until one of the following things happens:

The Random Walk reaches position=10 (successful termination condition)

100,000 Steps are taken and position=10 is still not reached (unsuccessful termination condition)


I wrote the following R simulation to represent random simulations of this Random Walk with these conditions:
library(ggplot2)

num_simulations <- 1000
max_steps <- 100000
target <- 10
steps <- numeric(num_simulations)
trajectories <- list()
terminated <- 0


for (i in 1:num_simulations) {
    position <- 0
    print(i)
    trajectory <- c(0)
    for (step in 1:max_steps) {
        position <- position + sample(c(-1, 1), 1)
        trajectory <- c(trajectory, position)
        if (position == target) {
            steps[i] <- step
            break
        }
        if (step == max_steps) {
            terminated <- terminated + 1
        }
    }
    trajectories[[i]] <- trajectory
}


termination_percentage <- (terminated / num_simulations) * 100


df1 <- data.frame(simulation_index = 1:num_simulations, log_steps = log(steps))
df2 <- data.frame(simulation_index = rep(1:num_simulations, sapply(trajectories, length)),
                  step = unlist(lapply(trajectories, seq_along)) - 1,
                  position = unlist(trajectories))


p1 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x = simulation_index, y = log_steps)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line() +
    labs(x = "Simulation Index", y = "Log(Number of Steps)",
         title = paste("Random Walk Simulations (Terminated:", termination_percentage, "%)")) +
    theme_bw()

p2 <- ggplot(df2, aes(x = step, y = position, group = simulation_index)) +
    geom_line(alpha = 0.1) +
    labs(x = "Step", y = "Position",
         title = paste("Trajectories of Random Walk Simulations (Terminated:", termination_percentage, "%)")) +
    theme_bw()

As we can see, roughly 2% of all simulations (with these initial conditions) met the unsuccessful termination condition.

My Question: Given a set of initial conditions and a set of termination conditions, is it possible to derive an expression for the expected number (i.e. expected value) of simulations expected to meet the unsuccessful termination condition?
Thanks!

Does "meeting the terminal condition" mean taking 100000 steps and 100 is not reached? That's what I get from your code. Because technically speaking the walk always meet one of the terminal conditions.

@ioveri : thank you for your reply! my apologies, what I meant was: the termination condition is taking 100000 steps. I have made made an edit in the question to clarify. Think of it this way : if position=100 before 100000 steps then successful termination else unsuccessful termination. I am interested in studying "unsuccessful terminations". Thank you so much!

@stats_noobs the target you set is 10, and not 100 so the probability is lower than it should be. Please update your program and image

@ioveri: thank you for pointing this out.  I updated it

I made several corrections to my answer and added some results I got (I didn't plot the trajectories since it would be too slow and cost me too much memory)

@ioveri: thank you so much for your answer, it's very kind of you. Do you know how to mathematically derive the formula for the first hitting time? Could you please show me if you have time? Thank you so much!

the solution is given in the Wikipedia link I cited. The brownian motion follows the heat equation and the solution corresponding the distribution particle's position surviving a certain amount of time is the solution of the heat equation with homogenous Dirichlet boundary condition (because the probability the surviving particle at the boundary is 0)

I've derived closed form expression for exact probability. It's based on reflection, I will edit the answer when I have time

@ioveri: thank you so much for all your help! I am looking forward to reading your derivation! I have accepted your answer as the official answer :)

EDIT: I've added the closed form expression of the probability
The probablity of unsuccessful walk after $n$ steps is given as follows
$$
P(n) = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} 2^{-n}p(k,n)$$
where
$$p(k,n)=\begin{cases}
\displaystyle\binom{n}{k} & k < x_c-x_0\\
\displaystyle\binom{n}{k} - \binom{n}{k+x_0-x_c}&x_c - x_0\leq k < \dfrac{n + x_c -x_0}{2}\\
0 &k \geq \dfrac{n + x_c - x_0}{2}
\end{cases}$$
or compactly
$$
P(n) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\lfloor\frac{1}{2}(n+x_c-x_0)\rfloor} 2^{-n}\binom{n}{k} - \sum_{k = x_c-x_0}^{\lfloor\frac{1}{2}(n+x_c-x_0)\rfloor} 2^{-n}\binom{n}{k+x_0-x_c}$$
The function $p(k,n)$ represents the number of paths that reach position $x = x_0-n+2k$ without reaching the termination target $x_c$. Hence $P(n)$ is the sum of $p(k,n)$ for all $x$, with the weight $2^{-n}$ for each path. In order to derive the formula of $p(n)$ we need to prove the following relation
$$\text{TNOW to reach } x\text{ from } x_0 \text{ without reaching }x_c\\= \\ \text{TNOW to reach } x\text{ from } x_0 - \text{TNOW to reach }x \text{ from } 2x_c - x_0$$
TNOW stands for "the number of ways" or the number of random walks. Let $X(i)$ be the position at step $i$ of a random walk that crosses or touches the boundary $x_c$. Let's define the reflection $R$ that maps the random walk $X$ to another random walk $Y_X$ by the following formula
$$Y_X(i) = \begin{cases}
2x_c - X(i) &i < L\\
X(i) &i \geq L
\end{cases}$$
where $L$ is the last step that at which the randow walk reached the position $x_c$. The figure below illustrates how the function is defined

This function maps random walk that starts from  point $x_0$ and ends at $x$ to a random walk that starts at point $2x_c-x_0$ and also ends at $x$, given they reach the boundary at least once, and vice versa. Furthermore, this reflection is an involution i.e. $R(R(X)) = X$, hence it is bijection between these set of random walks. And therefore their numbers are equal. Since the number of RW that reach $x$ and don't reach $x_c$ = the number of RW that reach $x$ - the number of RW that reach x and reach $x_c$ at some step(s), this gives us the relation aforementioned.
This reflection is the technique that is used to prove the reflection principle
The last thing we need to do is calculate the number of RW that starts from $x_0$ and $2x_c - x_0$, which are given by binomial distribution. This gives the formula of $p(k,n)$ Q.E.D.
Here's the old answer with approximation
The amount of time for a random process to reach a certain point for the first time is known as the first hitting time. For a Brownian motion, the survival probability of particle remains at the posittion $x < x_c$ at time $t$ is given by
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\erf}{erf}
S(t) =\erf\left(\frac{x_c-x_0}{2\sqrt{Dt}}\right)$$
where $D$ is the diffusion constant. The expected number of trials until the first hitting time is larger than $t$ is $\dfrac{1}{S(t)}$. A 1D random walk with time step $\delta$ and step size $\epsilon$ is approximately a 1D Brownian motion with $D=\dfrac{\epsilon^2}{2\delta}$, thus
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\erf}{erf}
S_{\mathrm{RW}}(t)\approx \erf\left(\frac{x_c-x_0}{2\sqrt{\frac{\epsilon^2t}{2\delta}}}\right)$$
Given $\delta = 1, \epsilon = 1, x_c = 100, x_0 = 0$ we have $S(100000) \approx \mathrm{erf}(0.3863) \approx 0.2481\%$ and the expected number of trials is approximately $4.03$
The data given in the program, however, correspond to $x_c = 10$ (targer <- 10) and so $S(100000) \approx \mathrm{erf}(0.03863) \approx 2.52\%$ . $10$ is quite low and the lower $x_c$ leads to higher error in the approximation.
Edit: I've also used Python and in R to test it out (not very efficient though)
import random
t = []
target = 100
trials = 1000
for i in range(trials):
    x = 0
    for j in range(100000):
        x += -1 + random.randint(0,1)*2
        if x == target:
            t.append(j)
            break   
    print(f"Trial {i+1} finished after {j+1} steps")

print(1 - len(t)/trials)

R:
num_simulations <- 1000
max_steps <- 100000
target <- 100
steps <- numeric(num_simulations)
trajectories <- list()
terminated <- 0


for (i in 1:num_simulations) {
  position <- 0
  print(i)
  for (step in 1:max_steps) {
    position <- position + sample(c(-1, 1), 1)
    if (position == target) {
      steps[i] <- step
      break
    }
  }
  if (step == max_steps) {
    terminated <- terminated + 1
  }
}


sprintf("The percentage of unsuccessful attempts is %f %%", (terminated / num_simulations) * 100)

I got $22.6\%$ and $24.4\%$ for $x_c = 100$ and $2.5\%$ and $3.2\%$ for $x_c = 10$. which are quite close to the estimation

Thank you so much for this wonderful answer! Really looking forward to your updated answer about the derivation of hitting times involving the reflection principle! :)

@stats_noob I've updated my answer

Wow this is such a beautiful answer ... thank you so much for this!

I am currently working on this - do you have any ideas about this question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4903926/when-is-the-hitting-time-of-a-random-walk-infinite thank you so much!

The weight $2^{-k}$ is replaced by $p^(n-k)(1-p)^k$ in the discrete case. In the continuous you just shift the distribution by $t(2p-1)$ because the limit of a biased random walk is a Brownian motion with drift

@stats_noob I'd look at that problem later. The meeting within range case with constraints might be difficult
